# Program to find vowels, If statements not assigning correct values

Tags: c, arrays, string, if-statement

I have a simple program to find the vowels in a string. The for loop is supposed to iterate through the string and see if the char matches any of the vowels using and if else block but the output is just 100 As.

I tried making them all just ifs but that gave all Us.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 100;

    char str[SIZE] = {"the brown fox\0"};
    char vowels[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++) {

        if (str[i] == '97' || '65') {

            vowels[i] = 'a';

        }

        else if (str[i] == '101' || '69' ) {

            vowels[i] = 'e';

        }

        else if (str[i] == '105' || '73') {

            vowels[i] = 'i';

        }

        else if (str[i] == '111' || '81') {

            vowels[i] = 'o';

        }

        else if (str[i] == '117' || '85')  {

            vowels[i] = 'u';

       }

        printf("%c", vowels[i]);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Fixed the assignment if e.g. (str[i] == '97' || str[i] == '65') now it's printing strange symbols

EDIT 2: New code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 100;

    char str[SIZE] = {"the brown fox\0"};
    char vowels[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++) {

        if (str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'A') {

            vowels[i] = 'a';

        }

        else if (str[i] == 'e' || str[i] =='E' ) {

            vowels[i] = 'e';

        }

        else if (str[i] == 'i' || str[i] == 'I') {

            vowels[i] = 'i';

        }

        else if (str[i] == 'O' || str[i] == 'o') {

            vowels[i] = 'o';

        }

        else if (str[i] == 'u' || str[i] == 'U')  {

                vowels[i] = 'u';

             }

            printf("%c", vowels[i]);

        }

        return 0;
   }
```

EDIT 3: Even after initialing vowels to '' at the start of the loop as suggested the strange symbols are gone but it's still not functioning properly.

Comment: `i <= SIZE` <-- Boom !

Comment: `str[i] == '97' || '65'` does not do what you think. You need `str[i] == 97 || str[i] == 65`, unquoted. But there are better ways to do this!

Comment: Please, take a look at this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OR and less than operators not working as intended C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373509/or-and-less-than-operators-not-working-as-intended-c-language)

Comment: does `str[i] == '97'` even compile ? Didn't you mean `str[i] == 97` or `str[i] == 'a'` ?

Comment: When you do get the `if` statement working, you aren't initializing your `vowels` array.  Also, your `for` loop is blowing completely past the end of your string.

Comment: I suggest you start your loop with `char c = tolower(str[i]);`. Then test if c is equal to any of `'a'`, `'e'`, `'i'`, `'o'` or `'u'` and if it is then just `putc(c)`, else do nothing. And end (after the loop) by printing a line break. You don't need a vowels array. You can get the character to print by using the input character.

Comment: Use the actual letters. It is easier to read and portable. `if (str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'A')`

Comment: It's printing strange symbols because you're always printing vowels[i] even if this isn't a vowel, and as hymie says you aren't initialising the vowels array. So it'll print random characters for whatever was in the memory beforehand.

Comment: @Cid Well, sort of: https://wandbox.org/permlink/7tXEexToO0kw8l2D The warnings are helpful, though.

Comment: One change you could make to see what's going on is to put a `vowels[i] = ' ';` at the start of your loop before the first if. (Or in an 'else' after the last if.) You'll then get spaces for non-vowels in your output. If that's not what you want, you'll have to do something else e.g. add some logic for whether you printf vowels[i] or not. You'll also see that your vowels output carries on past the end of your input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very large number of small problems summarized below:

```
#define SIZE 100    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
...
    char vowels[SIZE] = ""; /* initialize all zero, {0) is valid also */
```

An *integer constant* is created by `#define` or by use of an `enum`. A `const` qualified `int` is not a *constant integer*. (that said VLAs are legal in C99, but optional in C11)

```
    int idx = 0;            /* separate index for filling vowels array */
```

Keep a separate index for filling the `vowels` array.

```
        /* don't use magic-numbers in your code */
        if (str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'A') {
```

Don't use *magic-numbers*, instead, use literal character constants were needed in your code to produce much more readable code.

Your program takes arguments, use them to pass the string to parse (or read from `stdin`), e.g.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    const char *str = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "the brown fox";
    ...
```

The `test ? if_true : if_false` operator is called the *ternary* operator. It allows a simple in-line conditional to select one of two values based on the `test` condition (e.g. `(argc > 1)`)

If you plan on using `vowels` as a string, don't forget to *nul-terminate* vowels after the loop, e.g.

```
    vowels[idx] = 0;                /* nul-terminate vowels */
```

Correcting all the errors and adding the arguments to `main()` you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    const char *str = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "the brown fox";
    char vowels[SIZE] = ""; /* initialize all zero, {0) is valid also */
    size_t idx = 0;         /* separate index for filling vowels array */

    for (int i = 0; idx < SIZE - 1 && str[i]; i++) {
        /* don't use magic-numbers in your code */
        if (str[i] == 'a' || str[i] == 'A') {
            vowels[idx++] = 'a';    /* assign 'a', increment index */
        }
        else if (str[i] == 'e' || str[i] == 'E' ) {
            vowels[idx++] = 'e';
        }
        else if (str[i] == 'i' || str[i] == 'I') {
            vowels[idx++] = 'i';
        }
        else if (str[i] == 'o' || str[i] == 'O') {
            vowels[idx++] = 'o';
        }
        else if (str[i] == 'u' || str[i] == 'U')  {
            vowels[idx++] = 'u';
        }
    }
    vowels[idx] = 0;                /* nul-terminate vowels */
    printf (" %zu vowels: ", idx);  /* print number of vowels */
    for (int i = 0; vowels[i]; i++) /* output each vowel, comma-separated */
        printf (i > 0 ? ", %c" : "%c", vowels[i]);
    putchar ('\n');                 /* tidy up with newline */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
bin\vowels.exe "a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
 11 vowels: a, u, i, o, o, u, o, e, e, a, o
```

Comment: `i < SIZE - 1 && str[i]` is a bit redundant, why not rather use `while (str[i])` ?

Comment: Good catch, that should be `idx < SIZE - 1`. (to protect the array bounds of `vowels`)

Comment: Ah now it makes sense. Great answer, nicely detailled

Comment: (I hadn't had that 2nd cup of coffee yet...`:)`

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing your char `str[i]` with `'97'`

> 6.4.4.4
>
> An integer character constant has type int. The value of an integer character constant containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character is the numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer. The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is implementation-deﬁned.

If you want to compare a char you can use the ascii value for example `97` or directly the char with `'c'`.

For more maintenability and readability I prefer using the char directly.

There is other problems in your code:

First, in your for loop: `for (int i = 0; i <= SIZE; i++) {`
You are going too far in your array because of your `<=` as arrays id starts with `0`, if you type `str[100]`, in reality you are using the 101st char.

Another problem is your if statements: `if (str[i] == '97' || '65') {`

Here your if statement is equivalent to `if (str[i] == '97' || '65' != 0) {`

Consider retyping `str[i] ==` : `if (str[i] == '97' || str[i] == '65') {`

Plus don't forget the first problem I mentionned about your `'97'`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your compiler `str[i] == '117'` (and the rest) may give you an error as signle quotes are only to be used when you want to implement the ascii equivalent of a single character like `'a'` or so. Therefore `str[i] == '117'` is checking if `str[i]` is equal to the ascii equivalent of "117".

Other than that " || " is a logical "or" operator. When you write down `str[i] == '111' || '81'` you simply mean "find ascii codes of 111 and 81(which dont exist) , use them in "or" operation, check if the result equals str[i]".

last but not least i found a nice function online which might help making your code more compact

```
int isvowel(int ch)
{
     int c = toupper(ch);

     return (c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U');
}
```

to explain it shortly, if the char equivalent of given `int ch` is lowercase, the function changes it to uppercase and checks if it is an uppercase vowel, if the given integer already equals an uppercase vowel `int c = toupper(ch);` doesnt change anything.

Implementation can be done as:

```
for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)    //scan all emelents of str[SIZE]
{
    if(isvowel(str[i]))        //print if vowel
        printf ("%c", str[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please note the quote from the standard in the other answer.  Multi-character character constants are allowed in C, but the value is implementation defined.

Comment: Unfortunately changing them to actual characters didn't help but that function is a lot nicer anyway. Thank you.